# Error: Internal Server Error (500)? wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to import the demo data of WordPress—I get an error like this :

```
Error: Internal Server Error (500)
```

Here is the log file :

```
"The import files for: Zox News Demo Import were successfully downloaded!
Initial max execution time = 30
Files info:
Site URL = http://13.127.201.92/wordpress
Data file = /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/zox-news/import/zox-news.xml
Widget file = /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/zox-news/import/zoxnews.wie
Customizer file = not defined!
Redux files:
not defined!"
```

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: show php log file

Comment: Check here... https://wordpress.org/support/topic/data-file-not-defined/